# Tools to minify CDD and JS files

Tags: javascript, css, compression, minify, jscompress

I deployed my application, I find that the loading time is much .. there isa way to compress css and js files ? , knowing that I use in each page that the necessary and sometimes js version minified .. thank you

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with compressing JS files, use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2), and CSS files I prefer using [Compass with Sass](http://compass-style.org/), which not only can minify CSS files, but also support the superior (personal opinion) SCSS-syntax.

Both engines work well along with [GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/), which is a [NPM module](https://www.npmjs.com/) and a tool to perform various tasks. I use the following plugins with Grunt:

- [Grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) for the Compass tasks
- [Grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) for the UglifyJS tasks
- Additionally [Grunt-contrib-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) if you just want to concatenate various files
- And several other modules to run a local server, optimize images, etc. Have a look at the [plugins page for GruntJS](http://gruntjs.com/plugins).